# How do I get projection of one list to another with Linq?

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, projection

There are two classes:

```
public class Persons
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}

public class Phones
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get projection of Persons for PhoneList with linq:

```
List<Persons> personList = List<Persons>{...};

List<PhoneList> phoneList = persons...
```

How do I get it?

Comment: So you've basically never touched LinQ and instead of searching for a tutorial you thought it'd be better to ask a question? Or is there something we are missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Select` clause for projection:

```
List<PhoneList> phoneList = personList.Select(x => new Phones { Name = x.Name, Phone = x.Phone }).ToList();
```